# How to define custom highlight color?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, add-in

I'm able to highlight text but I'd like to use custom highlight colors. Even if I define custom colors, Word seems to use one of the colors in the default palette that it thinks is closest.

```
myRange.font.highlightColor = "#ffcc00"; // Should be orange. Comes out red
```

That color should come out orange but it comes out red.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word does not support custom highlight colors - only the traditionl, basic sixteen colors. This is a limitation of the Word application, not the Office JS APIs.

It would be possible to apply custom colors using *Shading*, however (as in borders and shading).

Comment: ooooo! That's nice! I'm going to try that!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a work-around to **the problem of *defining custom highlight colors*** which I discovered quite some time ago ..

If you paste in **highlighted text copied from an application from outside of Word** (i.e., highlighted text from an AOL email let's say), you can then:

1. Use the insertion bar to ***select and highlight* an area of the text** you just pasted in
2. Press the **FORMAT PAINTER** tool to copy the formatting of the area you've selected. **The pointer changes to a PAINTBRUSH icon (with an insertion bar attached)**
3. Move the PAINTBRUSH to the existing Word text that you want to highlight using the new color
4. Press and hold the mouse button (usually the left button) while selecting the specific text
5. Release the mouse button to apply the new highlighting and formatting

**The applied highlighting will also include any other existing formatting**; so you MAY have to change the font or adjust some other feature (i.e., turn on/off bold, italics, underline, etc.) But this is easily accomplished. The point is that ***you can now have ANY color highlighting that you prefer*** – this hack absolutely DOES work!

Here's, one last thing – when you save the document (by clicking the **OFFICE BUTTON** in the upper left corner), I would advise that you first select **WORD OPTIONS, then SAVE** and check the box next to **"Embed fonts in the file"** under **"Preserve fidelity when sharing this document"** (I always uncheck the other two boxes). This is to ensure that before you export or print the document, you may be sure that all the fonts and features have been saved within it.

And for the record, ***this technique is NOT shading***.

The highlighting comes ***from actual HIGHLIGHTED TEXT*** copied from a document or application ***from OUTSIDE of Word. So it has nothing whatsoever to do with Word's shading feature***. I've even copied highlighted text from ***non-dedicated word processing applications***, and then pasted the text into Word – where **it is then available to apply the copied highlighting to text within the existing Word document**.

If you think about it – the fact that **Word 2007 permits you to define *any THEME color* you want** clearly shows that **one *should* be able to *define* ANY desired custom HIGHLIGHTING color as well** – besides just the **15 basic colors** (and excluding the "no color"). And this work-around proves that this is so. The ***problem*** is that the **Word application itself does not permit you to accomplish this *directly***.

Comment: I bet this is not highlight but shading that gets copied. The accepted answer already mentions that custom colors are possible through shading.